# For loop and hoisting

Tags: javascript

I have a question.
For example I use `for` loop like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < some_length; i++ ) {
    /* some code */
}
```

After that variable `i` is hoisted.
Does it mean that I always should declare `i` variable at the beginning of the scope?

```
var i;

for ( i = 0; i < some_length; i++ ) {
    /* some code */
}
```

UPD:
I know that both loops work the same way.
I mean which one is more correct?

Comment: Both means the same thing, just that first one is more readable.

Comment: And whole thing makes more sense when it is wrapped in `function-block`

Comment: "Does it mean that I always should declare i variable at the beginning of the scope?" — That's a matter of opinion. There's no difference as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: If you manually hoist sometimes having a easily scannable list of declarations in a row can give you a good indication if a function needs refactoring (ie loadsavars, bad)... sometimes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modern JavaScript supports [block scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) via `let`.

```
for ( let i = 0; i < some_length; i++ ) {
    /* i is defined here */
}
/* i is not defined here * /
```

Back to the original quetion: which example is more correct?

I would argue that the second one is less error prone.

Comment: Link is password protected.

Answer (score 2):

In your example - first one is classic type declaration of your iterator variable. In other cases like when you operate on many functions/objects/variables i recommend you to declare all variables on the beginning of your scope/object/function.

When you see code wrote in that way in future it will be much easier to see what is going on in here. You just look on first 10-15 lines of code and you would not search for every variable inside - everything will be explained in the beggining of your code.

Comment: but more correct in FOR LOOP is your first example. Its casual declaration in many many languages.